# CMS C1 top.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: iis, iis-7, composite, c1-cms

I don't know if this is the place to post this question, but i really hope someone have any idea how to fix it.

**If this is not the place i will erase it**

1. I have developed a site using Composite C1
2. I have uploaded it to my hosting provider "LiveDns"
3. I always logged out immediately after login to the admin area of the site

I have check the console, and i am getting the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
top.js

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)    
services/ConsoleMessageQueue/ConsoleMessageQueueServices.asmx
```

I have applied all proper folder permission...

Just to note, when i deployed it on my local IIS everything work just fine!
I have also used to work with Arvixe hosting provider and everything work smoothly

Any one have any clue?

I guess this is not a code problem but deployment problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the hosting provider had to assign more memory and change the option to allow the site to run in Full trusted mode for this problem to be solved.

Nothing was wrong in the code